# What ref does and why it's necessary in iframes?

Tags: reactjs, iframe, ref

```
import React from 'react'

function MyComponent() {
    return (
        <div>
            <p style={{color: 'red'}}>Testing to see if my component renders!</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Now, let’s create a file  CustomIframe.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { createPortal } from 'react-dom'

const CustomIframe = ({
  children,
  ...props
}) => {
  const [contentRef, setContentRef] = useState(null)

  const mountNode =
    contentRef?.contentWindow?.document?.body

  return (
    <iframe {...props} ref={setContentRef}>
      {mountNode && createPortal(children, mountNode)}
    </iframe>
  )
}

export default CustomIframe;
```

1. What is ref in return doing ? and Why it's needed ? and Why put setContentRef instead contentRef     in ref={}?
2. Other than this, Why {...props} is present in iframe tag, when they are not consumed anywhere?

I tried finding ref online, only got to know about useRef hook, not ref

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `setContentRef` will assign iframe element reference to `contentRef` so you could access native methods and properties available in the iframe such as `contentWindow`
2. `{...props}` will spread out all the values in the props as attributes to the
   iframe element

Comment: what is ref and why need to pass ref in inframe tag

Comment: if you want to access native methods from your component like `contentWindow`, ref will attach the element reference to the variable through ref

Comment: ok, last 2 questions 
1) As  ref={setContentRef} in iframe, and state value is null, so we passing null in ref, or is it like somewhere in between value has been updated from null to MyComponent

2) Is ref attribute of iframe only or part of JavaScript

Comment: At the time of the reder, react will assign ref value to variable. Ref is available for every HTML element. not only iframe

Comment: Hi Sachila, as we always update state by function in React, 
but here to update contentRef from null to iframe body, why we not doing  setContentRef(contentRef?.contentWindow?.document?.body) ?

thanks again for your patience

Comment: because ref is doing that internally so we don't have to explicitly set it